# Build hook in Astro Integration API

Tags: astrojs

What hook is used to build an external template or component?
I want to use yew component (with client: load) and to do this i need to implement Astro Integration.

`astro:config:done` used to

> "retrieve the final config for use in other hooks",

which should be used *before* build, but everything after that hook ("`astro:server:setup` when running in “dev” mode, or `astro:build:start` during production builds") depends on environment, and i think implementing the build logic twice is a bad idea.